# Unable to redirect page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, cookies, redirect

I have grid on my asp.net page. grid having 3 columns with hyper links. both links working properly. but one is not redirecting desired page. I tried in different browsers as well . but got different error : as

```
 In Mozilla Firefox :The page isn't redirecting properly


     description In Mozilla Firefox :


Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
*   This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept
      cookies.
 In Google chrome : `This webpage has a redirect loop`



      description In Google chrome : 

The webpage at http://myserver:425/(S(c0kr2xuftxiwhm25cm4vjg45))/mypage.aspx?type=2&userId=8 has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.
```

since i tried lot of solutions over net , as i tried cleared cookies from browsers, added

```
<sessionState 
cookieless="false" // True also tried
timeout="10">
</sessionState>
```

in web config file but problem is same there. I checked link is properly redirecting desired page. I mean i checked spelling of my link it is perfect. what else i have to try to resolve it ? where should i am making mistake ?

```
<ItemTemplate>
                    <a href="mypage.aspx?type=2&userId=<%#Eval("userId") %>">Go to my page </a>

                </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant code for the grid?

Comment: it is huge but ...see a snip of code .

Comment: have you tried this solution "Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem" mentioned in the chrome error.

Comment: Thanks Furqan. I tried only clear all cookies. but since say i am running first time in browser though i am getting same issue. I checked it from different terminal where this site never opened before. so certainly there should not any cookie for this site. I must be issue of my web.cofig i guess. but unfortunately unable to resolve it yet

Comment: @Ronald Wildenberg: please check my question again , I have added code bit

Comment: Is the grid in a masterpage that mypage.aspx uses?

Comment: the grid by itself (in the snippet you posted) is not doing a redirection. You have a normal link to mypage.aspx. The issue seems to be in mypage.aspx itself. Try looking for a response.redirect in mypage.aspx.cs.

Comment: Sceen is : i have master page as mymaster.master. and this page is mygridpage.aspx where grid is populated. this gridpage in content page of mymaster page. where as i am redirecting to mypage.aspx from grid populated on mygrid.aspx page. where should i have to check ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do check anywhere , are you redirecting same page ? I think you need to check each condition throughly , you must be redirecting same page either with same parameter or with different parameters.

Comment: You are right , i was redirecting same page when page load get failure. by using     Response.Redirect(Request.Url.PathAndQuery); Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Try adding runat="Server" attribute to the link tag, like this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
                    <a runat="Server" ID="linkID" href="mypage.aspx?type=2&userId=<%#Eval("userId") %>">Go to my page </a>

                </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: it is saying server tag not formatting properly due to use of Eval()

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious place to check is inside `mypage.aspx` or `mypage.aspx.cs` for a redirect (see comment by paolo). The problem is not the link from the grid, this is simply a link.

What happens in this case is that you arrive at `mypage.aspx`, are redirected to `mypage.aspx` where you are redirected to `mypage.aspx`, etc.

Comment: yes i also tried to set breakpoint on page load event of mypage.aspx. but before to come at page load event it appearing this error. I found something, that I think my page is not accepting the querystring values. if i try only mypage.aspx or mypage.aspx?type= Not mypage.aspx?type=2 it is working i means redirecting properly. but why sohuld it is not accepting any querystring value ? Is this routing issue i guess?

Comment: What happens when you go to `mypage.aspx` directly? Or `mypage.aspx?type=2`. Without using the link from the grid.

Comment: I am able to access page by this: mypage.aspx directly . but certainly not  getting requires values of type and user id . But by mypage.aspx?type=2 it showing exact error what i explained in my question. second option (mypage.aspx?type=2) is not redirect to page and hence can not enter in page load event.

Comment: What do you mean by your last sentence? Can you also show us the `Page_Load` method of `mypage.aspx`? I still think something is wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this if you have one field in query string. Here in your case you have userid,

```
<asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Your Header" 
 DataNavigateUrlFields="userId" 
  DataTextField="Your Data Field to Display" 
 HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
  DataNavigateUrlFormatString="mypage.aspx?type=2&userId={0}" 
 ItemStyle-Width="35%"  
 ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" 
   />
```

In case of multiple

1) DataNavigateUrlFields="userId, employeeId, departmentid"

2) DataNavigateUrlFormatString="mypage.aspx?type=2&userId={0}&employeeId={1}&deptid={2}"

sequence of 1 and 2 must be same.